# SSE instruction set not enabled in eclipse under Win7

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc

I am using eclipse gcc on windows7, with intel core i5 cpu. i tried building the project. however, it end up with an error, saying #error "SSE instruction set not enabled". The location pointed to c:\mingw\x32-4.8.1-posix-dwarf-rev5\mingw32\lib\gcc\i686-w64-mingw32\4.8.1\include\xmmintrin.h
I wonder if anybody can provide some help. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144545/sse-instruction-set-not-enabled

Comment: the problem was due to the fact that i was using MinGW x32 instead of MinGW x64... now it is running well!

Comment: That's good news!  It also means that my "duplicate link" was inaccurate.  Could you post that as an answer to help future visitors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was due to the fact that i was using MinGW x32 instead of MinGW x64